# Joomla 2.5 pagination override

Tags: php, joomla, overriding, joomla2.5

I have changed one function in core pagination.php in libraries/html folder like that

```
protected function _list_render($list)
   {  
$stranky = JPagination::getPagesCounter();

      $html = '<ul>';
      $html .= '<li class="pagination-prev">' . $list['previous']['data'] . '</li>';


    $html .= '<li> &nbsp; | '. $stranky .' |&nbsp; </li>';

      $html .= '<li class="pagination-next">' . $list['next']['data'] . '</li>';
      $html .= '</ul>';

      return $html;
   }
```

This change works great but what i am trying to achieve is to have this code in override. so i put the same code in pagination.php in html folder in my template folder and change the name of the function to pagination_list_render($list)

```
function pagination_list_render($list)
   {  

$stranky = JPagination::getPagesCounter();


      $html = '<ul>';
      $html .= '<li class="pagination-prev">' . $list['previous']['data'] . '</li>';

        $html .= '<li> &nbsp; | '. $stranky .' |&nbsp; </li>';

      $html .= '<li class="pagination-next">' . $list['next']['data'] . '</li>';
      $html .= '</ul>';

      return $html;
   }
```

But now it does not work anymore and whole page is broken.

It seems that 
$stranky = JPagination::getPagesCounter();
is the problem.. in core file it works, in overriden file not.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your chrome file (pagination template override) does not have access to the JPagination object, so you have to calculate the values yourself.

```
public function pagination_list_render($list)
{
    $total   = count($list['pages']);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($list['pages'] as $i => $page) {
        if (!$page['active']) {
            $current = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    $counter = JText::sprintf('JLIB_HTML_PAGE_CURRENT_OF_TOTAL', $current, $total); 

    $html .= '<ul>';
    $html .= '<li class="pagination-prev">' . $list['previous']['data'] . '</li>';
    $html .= '<li> &nbsp; | '. $counter .' | &nbsp; </li>';
    $html .= '<li class="pagination-next">' . $list['next']['data'] . '</li>';
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Maybe you want to add a test, if there are more than 1 page.

Comment: If I call getPagesCounter() statically or with your sugested $this, the change in core file will produce good result. But if i put the same code (statically or with $this) in chrome file the result is always the same, broken pages. Nibra, could you please confirm that you have tried to override like this and it worked for you? If you try, maybe you find out where is the problem with this override. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it. You're right, the JPagination object is not available in the override. Corrected (and tested) the answer.

Comment: Your solution works! Thanks. I accept your answer. But one more question. There is really no way to include (call) JPagination object in this override method? I would prefer to use elegant way of using JPagination object instead of calculating it.

Comment: Well, yes and no. There is no way to access the JPagination object in the override function. On the other hand, you can create a TemplateHelper class with that function and include it into your template. From inside the template, you can access the view using `$this`, inject it into the override function and access the associated pagination. But that seems avoidable complicated to me.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the default pagination in my template like this:

Its really simple if you use jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( '.pagenav' ).removeClass( 'pagenav' ).addClass( 'pagination' );
    });
```

You can put anything in place of "pagination".
Similarly you can change for its children li

Hope that helps